# Как добавить текст с переменной в переменную

Tags: php

Как добавить в переменную еще одну переменную с текстом?

Например нужно вот так сделать, но не работает:

```
$segment = 'moskva';
$url = $segment.site.ru
echo $url;
```

Должно вывести moskva.site.ru

Comment: `$url = $segment.'.site.ru';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как `.site.ru` - это тоже строка, то можно сделать операции над строками, например сконкатенировать:

```
$segment = 'moskva';
$url = $segment . '.site.ru';
```

Или добавить переменную в строку:

```
$segment = 'moskva';
$url = "$segment.site.ru"; // "{$segment}.site.ru";
```